# Unable to pass none string parameters to TAG files

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, jsp-tags

I'm using JBOSS 4.0.2 with JSP 2.0. 
I have created a TAG file with the following directives:

```
<%@ attribute name="id" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="upgradeAccount" type="com.upc.domain.UpgradeAccountData" %>
```

However, when I try to pass an object of type `UpgradeAccountData` to the tag as a parameter it is always resolved as String, for instance :

```
<wmtags:paymentOptions id="23" upgradeAccount="${upgradeAccountCommand}">                   
</wmtags:paymentOptions>
```

in the above example the upgradeAccountCommand is passed as the `"${upgradeAccountCommand}"` string.( I've check it by defining the the type attribute in the tag as object and printing the object type and it's string value).

I've also made sure that the `upgradeAccountCommand` in the caller page is an actual `UpgradeAccountData` object.

What can I do to solve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *should* work; it sounds like EL expression evaluation might be turned off?  That could be due to `<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>` in the page, or the webapp is using the 2.3 servlet spec (or earlier).

Try this:

```
<wmtags:paymentOptions id="23" upgradeAccount="<%=upgradeAccountCommand%>">
```

Comment: I'm not so charmed of recommending old fashioned scriptlets as "the solution".

Comment: @BalusC Neither am I, but it'll narrow down the problem to EL being ignored.